# How do I select rows where only return keys that don't have '1' in column c

Tags: sql, t-sql

Title is confusing I know, I'm just not sure how to word this. Anyway let me describe with a table:

`| key | column b | column c |
|-----|----------|----------|
| a   | 13       | 2        |
| a   | 14       | 2        |
| a   | 15       | 1        |
| b   | 16       | 2        |
| b   | 17       | 2        |`

I'd like to select all keys where column c doesn't equal 1, so the select will result in returning only key 'b'

To clarify, my result set should not contain keys that have a row where column c is set to 1. Therefore I'd like a sql query that would return the keys that satisfy the previous statement.

To make my question as clear as possible. From the table above, what I want returned by some sql statement is a result set containing [{b}] based on the fact that key 'a' has at least one row where column c is equal to 1 whereas key 'b' does not have any rows that contain 1 in column c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.[Key]
FROM TableName t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TableName 
                  WHERE t.[key] = [key]
                   AND ColumnC = 1)
GROUP BY t.[Key]
```

Comment: Why use `GROUP BY <field list>` instead of just `DISTINCT`?

Comment: It is ambiguous: "ALL keys WHERE C <> 1" and result is only key `B`: not enough information, or ambiguous.  You will still get `A` in this query.  I do not believe this answer is correct.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause may or may not perform better than `DISTINCT` in most cases it would.

Comment: @frasnian please have a look at this [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ce7a/3) to see what your suggested query returns.

Comment: yes, that is exactly my point.  You asked for `ALL keys where column c doesn't equal 1`.  That is *exactly* what the query I suggested will give you.  The other part of your question `so the SELECT will result in returning only key 'b'`, is ambiguous.  There is nothing in your question to limit the result set.  You either need an additional condition to your WHERE clause, or your question is inherently unanswerable.  __On Edit__ adding as an answer because the existing answers are inherently wrong based on the question you actually asked.

Comment: This answer is wrong,  Read the question, and consider the part where OP says: "I'd like a sql query that would return the keys that satisfy the previous statement".  Remember that SQL is a set-oriented language (I get SO tired of typing that).  Based on the question, you will get 2 sets: {a, a}, {b ,b}.  So, the SELECT query to meet this constraint `the select will result in returning only key 'b'` will __require__ an additional constraint or condition in the WHERE clause.  This answer should not have been accepted, because it is flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT KEY
FROM  WhateverYourTableNameIs 
WHERE c <> '1'
```

Comment: This will return 1st two `A`s too since the ColumnC is not equal to 1.

Comment: "I'd like to select all keys where column c doesn't equal 1".  OP is apparently ambiguous about what they are asking.  If OP wants `= 1` that is a different query, just as simple.

Comment: `so the select will result in returning only key 'b'`

Comment: @M.Ali: and, based on the question, your query would be... Read it again: do you see TOP, UNIQUE, etc.?

Comment: nope `GROUP BY` will do the unique/distinct stuff for me.

Comment: @M.Ali: how does your comment:  `nope GROUP BY will do the unique/distinct stuff for me.`" address this?   Was this part of the OP's question?  Read it again, *as asked*.

Comment: Look, It was not my intention to phrase my question in any pseudo-sql manner. All I wanted was a sql query that could return keys (unique) based on the key not having a row that had column c set to 1. So since 'a' has a row with column c set to 1 do not return key 'a' in the set and since key 'b' does not have a row with column c set to 1, then include that in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `group by` and aggregation:

```
select [key]
from table t
group by [key]
having sum(case when c = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows that have `c = 1`.  The `= 0` says that there are no such rows for a given key.

Comment: You're answer works for this specific problem and I should have clarified that I wanted something more generic as the example I gave is very generic. Is there another way to do it if say column c contains varchar instead of an int

Comment: @WillHuang . . . This approach is quite generic.

Comment: @WillHuang . . . You would just compare to another string, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration based on other comments:

You asked for `ALL keys where column c doesn't equal 1`.  That is *exactly* what the query I suggested will give you.  The other part of your question `so the SELECT will result in returning only key 'b'`, is ambiguous.  The question *as asked* will give you results from columns A *and* B.  There is nothing in your question to limit the result set.  You either need an additional condition to your WHERE clause, or your question is inherently unanswerable.